# When to use Externalizable instead of writeReplace+readResolve?

Tags: java, serialization

In a couple of places I'm using `writeReplace` and `readResolve`, which sometimes gets quite verbose. I wonder if using `Externalizable` could be better (actually, I don't think so, because my objects are mostly immutable, but I may be wrong). Could you give me some good examples of using `Externalizable`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was told that `Externalizable` is much faster than default serialization, as it eliminates the reflection overhead. Working with final fields can be solved by using `writeReplace` and `readResolve`, too, as [I recently realized](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/project-lombok/RQ6VQRRMY38/YAHsmFv28soJ).

Comment: I can't see why Externalizable should be faster in general. It just allows you to implement the serialization yourself. Performance will depend on your implementation.

Comment: @Sandro I'm obviously assuming a "normal" implementation, which does about the same as `Serializable` does, just without the reflection overhead. Sure, you can add some overhead, if you really wanted to. Some compression could make sense (AFAIK some bloom filters implementations do it), but let's compare apples to apples.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how they are even comparable. writeReplace() etc writes a surrogate object for cases when you want to do that; Externalizable takes over the entire serialization of the *current* object and its base objects.

What was your motivation fo using writeReplace()?

Comment: There were different reasons. Recently I advised somebody to use `writeReplace` while serializing a class containing some svg document, which (for whatever reason) references the `AWTEventDispatcher`. Earlier I used it in order to make a class image much more compact (maybe a premature optimization).